# Use anonymous class generated by struct in ruby tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, here we have a file with struct,

```
module CoreDomain
  Corporation = Struct.new(...)
end
```

and we have such a test file,

```
require 'test_helper'

module CoreDomain
  class CorporationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def test_corporation_struct_creation
      corp_struct = CoreDomain::Corporation.new(...)

      assert_equal ..., ...
    end
  end
end
```

when I trying to execute the test I get this error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CoreDomain::Corporation
```

Question - where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Seems like Rails' autoloading isn't working properly. What's the name of the file you're creating the struct in? And can you use `CoreDomain::Corporation` in your Rails code or in `rails console`?

Comment: BTW, your struct class isn't anonymous once you assign it to a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is going actually going on here is that you're fooling the autoloader.

Since your test is nested inside `module CoreDomain` when you get to `CoreDomain::Corporation.new(...)` it won't trigger the autoloader to start looking for the `CoreDomain` constant. The classic autoloader worked by hacking its way onto `Object.const_missing` so was very prone to these kind of errors.

The solution is to just reference the constant before you reopen the module:

```
require 'test_helper'

CoreDomain::Corporation # take that you stupid autoloader!

module CoreDomain
  class CorporationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def test_corporation_struct_creation
      corp_struct = Corporation.new(...)

      assert_equal ..., ...
    end
  end
end
```

Or just remove the test class from the module.

Comment: Ironically `class CoreDomain::CorporationTest` would not have this issue since it would force the autoloader to load the CoreDomain module. It doesn't actually set the correct module nesting though.

Comment: A simpler solution could be `class CoreDomain::CorporationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase` which should trigger the autoloader for `CoreDomain`

Comment: @stefan yes - but the caveat is the surprising constant lookup caused by misusing the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was some misunderstanding, but all I need to do is to add this line

```
require_relative '../../core/domain/corporation.rb'
```

to the top of `test_corporation.rb` file